# Gmail not removing percent encoding while creating a pre-populated email url in swift

Tags: ios, swift, email, swift5

I am trying to add a suggestion/feedback section in my app. It's supposed to open a mail app with pre-populated text for the subject, body, and email address. It's working fine except the subject and body show the percent-encoding for space. I have searched a lot and it seems like an iOS 15 issue but I am not sure. This is my code:

```
private func createEmailUrl(to: String, subject: String, body: String) -> URL? {
    let subjectEncoded = subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    let bodyEncoded = body.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    
    
    let gmailUrl = URL(string: "googlegmail://co?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
    
    let outlookUrl = URL(string: "ms-outlook://compose?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)")
    let yahooMail = URL(string: "ymail://mail/compose?to=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
    let sparkUrl = URL(string: "readdle-spark://compose?recipient=\(to)&subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
    let defaultUrl = URL(string: "mailto:\(to)?subject=\(subjectEncoded)&body=\(bodyEncoded)")
    
    if let gmailUrl = gmailUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(gmailUrl) {
        return gmailUrl
    } else if let outlookUrl = outlookUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(outlookUrl) {
        return outlookUrl
    } else if let yahooMail = yahooMail, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(yahooMail) {
        return yahooMail
    } else if let sparkUrl = sparkUrl, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(sparkUrl) {
        return sparkUrl
    }
    
    return defaultUrl
}
```

And this is how I am calling the API

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

The Gmail app shows the subject as:

> Reg:%2520Suggestions/Feedback%2520About%2520iOS%2520App

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't an issue at all. I was sending an already encoded string and it was encoding % to %25. Hence all my encoded special characters were converted into %25__.

My bad. I must read the code properly before copy-pasting.